Why do we have a grid-like layout of nav waypoints over the Gulf of Mexico
This is an unusual feature found, apparently only over the Gulf of Mexico south of the Continental United States. There appears to be an array of NAV waypoints, evenly laid out in an 18 x 20 nautical mile grid, both over US territorial waters and international waters. These waypoint do not be seem to be associated with airways, both VFR and IFR low and high altitude routes.  I have wonder if this is a military arrangement, for aircraft operating with the United States, military, and Allied nations, such as Mexico to conduct flight operations and military exercises there (a lot of these waypoints lie in the warning areas off the Gulf Coast).  Does anybody know what these waypoints are used for?



It appears these waypoints are part of the helicopter sectional for the Gulf of Mexico.  I Would imagine it allows pilots to create very specific flight plans to get to the oil rigs in the Gulf.  The sectional shows the waypoints that OP found as well as a numbered grid.
Make your Flight Plan at SkyVector.com


Looks like this may be an extension of the NRS, see page 3 here.

See AIM 10-1.4 The Gulf of Mexico Grid System: "Flight plan routes are routinely defined by just 4 segments: departure point (lat/long), first en route grid waypoint, last en route grid waypoint prior to approach procedure, and destination point (lat/long)."

@RalphJ  That was the first thing I thought of when I read this post.
